# How can I get the iteration number when using lodash map on an object?

Tags: javascript, lodash

```
const things = {
  thing1: 'Thing 1',
  thing2: 'Thing 2',
  thing3: 'Thing 3',
};

const newThings = _.map(things, (thing, thingKey) => {
  console.log(thingKey, thing);
}
// Outputs:
// thing1 Thing 1
// thing2 Thing 2
// thing3 Thing 3
```

I need to know what the iteration number is on each loop. I could manually create a variable and then increment it on each loop iteration, but I was hoping for some built-in functionality of the lodash `map` method. Any tips?

```
let iterationNumber = 0;
const newThings = _.map(things, (thing, thingKey, collection) => {
  // Do some stuff
  if (iterationNumber === collection.length - 1) {
    // Do something when it is the last property 
  }
  iterationNumber++;
});
```

Comment: Do you need to use .map or any other itrating idea will work for you?

Comment: I need to use map, since I'm using it for React and will need to return an array of JSX

Comment: use a nomal map....  myArray.map( (index, item) => console.log(item, "at index: ", index)

Comment: `map` will only work for an array, but I suppose I could use `Object.entries()` to convert the object to an array.

Comment: Well there is no index if you arent using an array?

Comment: That's why I called it the iteration number and not necessarily an `index`

Comment: What do you mean ? In your own question you see that it informs interaction index in thingKey variable. If you already know how to get the interaction number, what's the question ?

Comment: @zeckdude than what do you mean by iteration number ? can you explain a bit more

Comment: thingKey is the interaction number provided by Lodash...

Comment: you can do Object.keys(things).map( key => { return {[key]: things[key]}}) to convert to an array

Comment: By iteration number I meant that I wanted to know which number of iteration we are on for each time the function gets run. So the first iteration would be `0`, then `1`, and so forth. Usually this is easily attained by accessing the `index` but since the lodash `map` method provides the `key` instead, you need to create a variable beforehand and iterate on that for each loop or you can use `Object.entries()` to convert the object to an array of arrays which each contain the key and value. Using this approach gives you access to the iteration number (index) each time the function is run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Object.entries()` to get key/value from `Object` and than map

```
   map (currentValue, index, array)
```

```js
const things = {
  thing1: 'Thing 1',
  thing2: 'Thing 2',
  thing3: 'Thing 3',
};


Object.entries(things).map(([key,value],index)=>{
  console.log(key,value,index)
})
```

Comment: The question specifically asked for `lodash` based solutions.

Answer (score 2):

With lodash you can use `_.overArgs()` to generate a function that converts the object to entries with `_.toPairs()` and calls `_.map()` with the entries:

```js
const { overArgs, map, toPairs } = _;

const mapObjectWIthIndex = overArgs(map, [toPairs]);

const things = {
  thing1: 'Thing 1',
  thing2: 'Thing 2',
  thing3: 'Thing 3',
};

const newThings = mapObjectWIthIndex(things, ([v, k], index, collection) => {
  if (index === collection.length - 1) return `${v} - last`;
  
  return `${v} - ${index}`;
});

console.log(newThings);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm still curious if there is a way to get the index from the `lodash` method, but this is the solution I came up with that works pretty well:

```
const newThings = Object.entries(things).map(([thingKey, thing], index) => {
  // Do some stuff
  if (index === collection.length - 1) {
    // Do something when it is the last property 
  }
});
```

Comment: The accepted answer has the same content and by the way both of the answers are not using Lodash.